Filter Expression for Nested Arrays using JSONpath for mapping application
Im trying to filter and get the first object of two objects that my array includes using Jsopath.
My JSON source is the following :


{
  "parties": {
    "applicants": [
      {
        "role": "USER",
        "companyType": "LEGAL_ENTITY",
        "contactDetails": {
          "residenceAddress": {
            "streetAddress": "testADDRESS",
            "postalCode": "12323",
            "city": "Athens",
            "country": "GR"
          },
          "email": "testing@tester.com"
        },
        "companyDetails": {
          "company": "COMPANY TESTING1",
          "refNo": "123213"
        },
        "id": "d2ed5f80-e6c6-4463-86f6-4600654f899d",
        "state": "CONFIRMED",
        "sequenceNumber": 1
      },
      {
        "role": "USER",
        "companyType": "LEGAL_ENTITY",
        "contactDetails": {
          "residenceAddress": {
            "streetAddress": "TESTADDRESS2",
            "postalCode": "1231232",
            "city": "Athens",
            "country": "GR"
          },
          "email": "TESTINGtest"
        },
        "companyDetails": {
          "company": "COMPANYTESTING2",
          "refNo": "423423"
        },
        "id": "d2ed5f80-e6c6-4463-86f6-4600654f899e",
        "state": "CONFIRMED",
        "sequenceNumber": 2
      }
    ] 
  } 
}



Things ive tried :

$.parties.applicants[?(@.role == 'USER')].companyDetails.company

Works. Brings both two objects.

($.parties.applicants[?(@.role == 'USER')].companyDetails.company)[0]

trying to bring the first object. not working.

$.parties.applicants[?(@.role == 'USER')][0].companyDetails.company

not working.
Im not sure if the logic im trying to implement ([0]) works or is appropriate  for what i want to accomplish. Ive been testing the JSON path on https://jsonpath.com/ evaluator.
Any help or ideas will be more than welcome.

Based on your JSON you could get the first element by doing this query $.parties.applicants[?(@.role == 'USER' && @.sequenceNumber == 1)].companyDetails.company. But maybe the sequenceNumber will not be always 1. If it's the case you should swap language and go for JMESPath it's a more complete language for querying json, jq too is good.

@bosskay972 thank your for your help and reply. Ive been testing and it seems to be working. One last question. How could i implement this if the sequenceNumber field did not exist in my JSON ?

as I said without the seuqenceNumber you have to change your querying language because regular json path will not cover this type of case. You can go and test it on this website : https://jmespath.org/ put your json in the right text fields then put this code @.parties.applicants[?@.role == 'USER'] | [0].companyDetails.company it will normally print exactly what you want. JMESPATH is a good querying language but have some limits, if you want to break all limit and querying something really complex you should use jq. But JMESPATH is easier to handle than jq.

@bosskay972 Thank you for the help!!!! You ve been more than helpful!

If I solve your subject could you please validate my answer please ? Thanks a lot

Here's the solution :
$.parties.applicants[?(@.role == 'USER' && @.sequenceNumber == 1)].companyDetails.company
But if you don't have access to sequenceNumber or if sequenceNumber is not the counter, you will have to change your querying language and use JMESPATH or Jq.
